# android app connect to magento via soap webservice

Tags: android, web-services, magento, soap

i am a android app developer. and i want to connect my android with magento with soap web service.

i run this code but i can't get the session id. 
so please help me to how i get the session id and if this code has something wrong then please correct this.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
private  static final String Method_Name="login";
private static final String URL ="http://abcd.com/api/v2_soap/";

TextView tv;
Context mContext;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

}

public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,Method_Name);
            request.addProperty("username", "suman");
            request.addProperty("apiKey", "suman123");

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopes = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelopes.dotNet = false;
                    envelopes.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    try 
                    {
                        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
                        androidHttpTransport.debug =true;
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelopes);//Getting the Exception here
                        SoapPrimitive resultString=(SoapPrimitive)envelopes.getResponse();
                        tv.setText("Status "+resultString);
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage(""+resultString).show();
                    } 
                        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage(""+e.toString()).show();
                    }


        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: please anybody reply, its urgent..

Answer (score 0):

i get sessionID with this code :

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
private static final String URL = "http://your_domain/index.php/api/v2_soap/";

SoapSerializationEnvelope env;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;
SoapObject request;
String sessionId = "";
Object result;
```

---

```
env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        env.dotNet = false;
        env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");
        request.addProperty("username", "xxxxx");
        request.addProperty("apiKey", "123456");
        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        (new MarshalHashtable()).register(env);
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        result = env.getResponse();
        Log.d("sessionId", result.toString());
        sessionId = result.toString();
```

Comment: Followed exactly what you said, and it gives me : `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html lang='en'>@2:17 in java.io.InputStreamReader@54276f60)` on `androidHttpTransport.call("", env);` Any idea what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

v2_soap is not working in your magento framework . So you better go with SOAP with the version 1.

use this

```
http://abcd.com/api/soap/
```

and give appropriate permissions for your android application project . like Internet , Wifi state if you are using , bluethooth is also needed , Network state ,

if you are using android studio , then paste this code in your MainActivity

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
             .detectDiskReads()
             .detectDiskWrites()
             .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
             .penaltyLog()
             .build());
     StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
             .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
             .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
             .penaltyLog()
             .penaltyDeath()
             .build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this class... its working for me...I am using **Android ksoap2** library...

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8888/Magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/";

private class magentoUserlogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Object result= null;
        try {

            SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            env.dotNet = false;
            env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");

            request.addProperty("username", "<urSOAP/XML username>");
            request.addProperty("apiKey", "<yourAPIKey>");

            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
            result = env.getResponse();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.d("sessionId", s.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Session ID: "+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```